# Reading System manual and large files

Tags: linux

How can I copy the description of cat command from the manual to the file named cat-man?
I have tried to the synopsis of cat command while it is always with a error that no file name cat-man or destination.

Comment: Are you trying to cat the contents of a man page to a file? It's unclear what you're asking about. Showing the command you're trying to run would definitely help.

Comment: concur with @slm; please reword this if you'd like the question to remain open.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$ man cat > cat-man
```

The `>` allows you to redirect `stdout` to a file name. In this case a file called: cat-man.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be:

```
sed '/^DESCRIPTION$/,/^[^ ]/!d' <(man cat) | head -n -1 > cat-man
```

Note that negative value for `head` is non POSIX.